# Remove Duplicate entry '59' for key 'PRIMARY in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am very new in Hibernate. I am using Hibernate with JPA. I have an annotated entity class and a table related to that entity class.

```
@Entity 
public class Test implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="inc" , strategy="identity")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="inc") 
    private int id; 

    private String address; // setter getter and constructor 
}
```

When saving this entity, it insert the data into the db. But during application running process another application is inserting data into same table. when my application try to save the data then Duplicate entry '59' for key 'PRIMARY' exception generated. So I want to use a generator which can insert the data and generate id in database level rather than application level and the identifier must saved back to my entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Table generator strategy or the sequence generator.

Comment: I agree with you. But I need a generator which can get the max(id) each time before inserting the entity. Bcz it's may be, someone manually insert the data into table. On that time Table generator also get failed. Kindly guide me.

Comment: If someone directly updates the table then in this you need to manually take care the ID, i.e before inserting the record fetch the max id and do +1 on it and persist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to specify a generator. You can use the default generator and never set the id manually. If the error still comes post your merge/persist method.

More informations about generators can you found here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; 

    private String address; // setter getter and constructor 
}
```